# i'm getting this Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered error

Tags: angularjs

Controller file

```
     var ToDo=angular.module('ToDo',[]);
ToDo.controller('resetPasswordController',function($scope,resetPasswordService,$location){
    $scope.resetPassword=function(){
        var message=resetPasswordService.resetPassword($scope.user);
        message.then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.message);
            if(response.data.message=="password is reset")
                $location.path("/login");
        });
    }

});
```

service file

```
 var ToDo = angular.module('ToDo',['ngResource']);
ToDo.factory('resetPasswordService', function($resource,$http) {
    var token=sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    var details = {};
    if(token!=null){
        console.log(token);
        sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
        details.resetPassword = function(user) {
            /*user.$save();*/
            return $resource('http://localhost:8080/ToDo/forgotPassword/resetPassword/:Token',{Token:token});
        }
    }
    return details;
});
```

mainapp.js

```
 var ToDo = angular.module('ToDo', [ 'ui.router']);
    ToDo.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',

    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('resetPassword', {
        url : '/resetPassword',
        templateUrl : 'template/resetPassword.html',
        controller : 'resetPasswordController'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('resetPassword');
    } ]);
```

template file

```
<form>
    <h3 align="center">Re-set New Password</h3>
    <div class="col-sx-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Enter New Password</label> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control"
                data-ng-model="user.newPassword" name="emailId" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sx-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Re-Enter The New Password</label> 
            <input type="password" class="form-control"
                data-ng-model="user.reEnterNewPassword" name="username" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sx-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="buttons" type="submit" data-ng-click="resetPassword()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sx-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                Want To try <a href="#!/login">Sign-In Again?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</form>
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/scriptpage.css">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="controller/resetPasswordController.js"></script>
```

>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/ToDoApp.js"></script>

</head>
<body data-ng-app="ToDo">
    <div data-ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i put ToDoApp.js before controller and service my view just goes to blank and when i put after those html page is showing but i get Error: $controller:ctrlreg
A controller with this name is not registered. for resetPasswordController
. Please help me with this problem.

And yes when i remove [ngResource] then everything works fine. Why??

Comment: Concerning the last point, it's due to a version compatibility. You're working with Angular **1.6.6**, then you should work with ngResource **1.6.6**, not *1.4.4*. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-resource.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining you 'ToDo' module multiple times. In the controller and service files you should just get that module

```
 var ToDo = angular.module('ToDo');
```

And in mainapp you should also inject ngResource

```
var ToDo = angular.module('ToDo', [ 'ui.router', 'ngResource']);
```